# bash syntax error expected operad

Tags: bash, recursion

I have this bash script that receives me the error mentioned below. Do you have any explanations?

```
#! /bin/bash

first=1
second=1
result=2
contor=2
fib()
{
        contor=$1
        if [ $contor -eq $n ]
        then
        echo  result
        else
        let $contor++
        let result=$first+$second
         first=$second
         second=$results
        fib $contor
        fi
}
read n
result=$(fib 2)
echo $reusult
```

Comment: Copy paste your script in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the errors shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least three problems here:

- `let $contor++` will actually substitute the value of `contor`, meaning the expression will be something like `let 42++`, which is invalid. Get rid of the `$`.
- `second=$results` will set `second` to something *other* than what's in `result`, which will probably cause an issue when you try to execute `let result=$first+$second`. Use the correct variable name.
- You print the variable `reusult` at the end, again a mis-spelling.

---

The way I found those issues is the same way you (or anyone, for that matter) should be finding them in `bash`, by temporarily putting the following lines at the top of your script to aid debugging:

```
set -e # stop on error
set -x # echo each interpreted line before execution.
```

There's are a great help when trying to figure out where the problems lie.

---

For what it's worth, Fibonacci is usually a *bad* candidate for recursion since you generally have to calculate things more than once.

That's because calculating `fib(1000)` as `fib(999) + fib(998)` usually entails a *massive* duplication of effort on either side of that `+` symbol.

That's not actually the case with your code because, while the code *is* calling itself, the leakage of information across levels really makes it an iterative solution - at no stage are you getting the *result* of `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)` to calculate `fib(n)`.

So, since you have an iterative solution anyway, you may as well remove the last vestiges of recursion and use something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

fib() {
    # Validate input argument to be integer 1...92.

    num=$1
    if [[ ! ${num} =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]] ; then
        echo "Invalid input '${num}'."
        return
    fi
    if [[ ${num} -gt 92 ]] ; then
        echo "Invalid input '${num}'."
        return
    fi

    # First two Fib's are both one.    

    if [[ ${num} -le 2 ]] ; then
        echo "1"
        return
    fi

    # For other Fib's, just iterate keeping previous two.

    grandparent=1 ; parent=1 ; child=2
    ((num -= 3))

    while [[ ${num} -gt 0 ]] ; do
        ((grandparent = parent))
        ((parent = child))
        ((child = grandparent + parent))
        ((num--))
    done

    echo ${child}
}

# Rather rudimentary test harness.

[[ "$(fib x)" != "Invalid input 'x'." ]] && echo Fail A && exit
[[ "$(fib -7)" != "Invalid input '-7'." ]] && echo Fail B && exit
[[ "$(fib 0)" != "Invalid input '0'." ]] && echo Fail C && exit
[[ "$(fib 93)" != "Invalid input '93'." ]] && echo Fail D && exit

[[ "$(fib 1)" != "1" ]] && echo Fail E && exit
[[ "$(fib 2)" != "1" ]] && echo Fail F && exit
[[ "$(fib 3)" != "2" ]] && echo Fail G && exit
[[ "$(fib 4)" != "3" ]] && echo Fail H && exit
[[ "$(fib 5)" != "5" ]] && echo Fail I && exit
[[ "$(fib 6)" != "8" ]] && echo Fail J && exit
[[ "$(fib 20)" != "6765" ]] && echo Fail K && exit
[[ "$(fib 50)" != "12586269025" ]] && echo Fail L && exit
[[ "$(fib 92)" != "7540113804746346429" ]] && echo Fail M && exit

# User test.

read -p "Which Fibonacci number (>= 1)? " n
result=$(fib $n)
echo $result
```

You'll notice the input is restricted to the range `1..92`. That's because, at some point (`92` is the last one that works for me), `bash` will start giving strange results because of limits of its internal data types.

Comment: He should also use local variables within `fib` otherwise they'll be modified out of scope. For this particular example though the vales will be the same.